# Why have a min-height but no actual height?

Tags: css

What does it mean when an element has a `min-height` but not a `height`?

```
div#single-post{
  min-height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just checked the site you gave and this is what I get

> div#single-post
>   {
>      background-color: #FFFFFF;
>      padding-left: 20px;
>      padding-right: 20px;
>   }

There is no min-height for this id. Are you missing something?

Min-Height with no height would be the sidebar. Did you mean this???
If so, it is because it should still be there if there is no entry (otherwise, it would like dismiss and your site would look different), but it should also be able to expand if you are using a lot of modules or whatsoever

Comment: Agreed but I think the user wants to know the difference between min-height and height?

Comment: Well as I wrote I made the example with the sidebar describing why it is usefull there

Comment: Im sorry i was wrong. you mean the height of the div will depend on the elements or items inside it?..

Comment: There will always be the min-height defined, it will not be less. But if the content of the div gets bigger than the min-height, there will be no overflow, but the div will increase it's size dynamically to fit the new content :) you can test  this by goin on your site and write in your browserbar: `javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0` then you can edit your site over javascript. now write something in your sidebar and you will see how it will increase its size dynamically and decrease if you remove things, but it will never just vanish

Comment: Edited the post to not depend on the link with the wrong information. You should update your answer...

Answer (score 2):

min-height sets a low-end threshold for the height of the element, but allows the content to control the height should the content exceed x px. Unlike the height property which doesn't allow the element to expand should content overfill the element set range.

min-width works in much the same way, except it does not allow content to dictate the width. Rather the minimum width is used to set limitations on how fluid page layouts resize when your browser window is adjusted. If you set min-width to 500px, the browser will not let your element shrink to less than 500px wide.

source:  http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/5671.htm

So by using min-height in different areas of the site the user does not have to worry about content being missing or hidden by height restrictions as he/she can rest assured that the element will expand.